# Op-Amp Selection for Dummies

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, dc

I am new to op amps, and I could use some help. I am trying to make a linear precision current supply and searching for the perfect op amp for the job. I have a design I know that works, at least on LTspice and another similar circuit in production. It is a high-side current limiter, as you can see below. I have selected two possible Op Amp candidates I am trying. I am using an LT6016 and an AD820. Both are Rail-to-Rail op-amps and seem to support what I am trying to do, but the AD820 fails on some test runs. Can someone look at it and tell me why?

Allow me to explain the circuit. The Zener provides the precision voltage reference to the R3/R5 voltage divider. R5 remains fixed at 10K, and R3 is variable from 500 to 1.5K to vary the current set point from 5 to 34 amps. R1 is the current sense resistor, and M1 and R7 simulate the load for testing. The LT6016 works flawlessly with excellent precision. Set R3 to 1.3636K, and you will see 30 amps. Lower R3 to 500 ohms, and you have 5-ish amps.

The AD820 works with R3 = 1.3636K, yielding 30 amps output as planned. Lower R3 to 500 ohms, and the circuit does not work, which drives me crazy. I thought I knew what I was looking for in op-amps, but as it turns out, I am wet behind the ears. Can someone please take a look and tell me what I missed and what to look for?

Thank You

[image]

Comment: You write, *"I am new to Op Amps"*. In general, and if possible, it's a good idea to operate opamp inputs within a few tens of millivolts between each other and both roughly in the middle of their power supply rails. Dividers can be used for this. Or BJT current mirror structures.

Comment: The loop gain in this design is very high, due to the common-source arrangement of M1. Any op-amp you use that has internal frequency compensation (which is nearly all of them) will *possibly* be unstable here. You may need to add some extra compensation. Or stick to the usual source-follower setup, which would be my advice.

Comment: Also, at the currents you have quoted, M1 will dissipate hundreds of watts under certain conditions. A single MOSFET is not a good idea here.

Comment: @simon, thank you. If I knew how to add compensation, I would do so. About M1, it is a driver to multiple 2N3055 BJT. This is a simplified circuit for proof of concept. It is part of a 12-volt, adjustable 5 to 30-amp CCCV battery charger and power supply.

Answer (score 6):

The title of the AD820 datasheet says it is "rail-to-rail", but if you look more at the front page bullet points it only says that the **output** swings rail to rail, and the input may be used below ground (i.e. below the negative supply rail). It doesn't say that the input is fully rail-to-rail. And the common mode input range spec says that the maximum input voltage is 1 V below the VCC rail. This is the spec for +/- 15 V supplies:

[image]

When you set R3 to 500 ohms, you're setting the input voltage to only about 110 mV below the positive rail, so there's no reason to expect the op-amp to work.

Now, when you set R3 to 1.36 kohms, you're only setting the input voltage 300 mV below the positive rail, and the datasheet gives you no promise the op-amp will work under those conditions either. But the SPICE model is based on typical behavior, not on a strict reading of the datasheet. So it may be that the circuit will work with a typical chip with R3 at 1.36 kohms. But it might not. Or it might work initially but then fail when the op-amp heats up above room temperature, or cools down significantly, or if the wind is blowing from the east, or whatever.

LT6016 is working in this design because it has a special "over-the-top" input design that allows input common mode range up to 76 V above the negative rail, regardless of the positive rail voltage.

If you need very high precision, one issue to watch out for with the LT6016 is that as the input voltage varies from about 1 V below the upper rail to the upper rail, there is a few uV change in the input offset voltage:

[image]

Since you're operating right in that range, you could see some noise or thermal drift beyond the ordinary specified limits in your design.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now and did not pick that up in the specs. I want to find something with Over The Top, which now leads me to LT4091. It looks like it was made to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the inputs of the AD820 will not properly work within 1 volt of the positive supply rail: -

[image]

Image from [data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad820.pdf).

You should also recognize that the AD820 has an input offset voltage of maybe as high as 1 mV and, 1 mV represents a current measurement error of 100 mA (when using a 0.01 Ω sense resistor).

It's also worth pointing out that if you are trying to control low currents with a low impedance load (presumably R7) you will possibly destroy the IRF510 due to thermal runaway. It happens when using the wrong sort of MOSFET i.e. one that is designed for switching applications and, you have a power supply capable of delivering tens of amps. Look at this graph in the data sheet: -

[image]

So, you may think your op-amp can control current but, thermal runaway can occur in less than 1 ms and, with such a large current capacity supply (whilst trying to regulate at 300 mA), you may be left scratching your head why the MOSFET fails with absolutely no sign of overheating but, if you took the lid of and looked inside, you would see that there is damage on or around the drain electrode.

Comment: Andy, thank you. I understand your comments referring to the MOSFET. I am not showing the whole circuit. I am showing you a snapshot of my constant current regulator used in a 12-volt DC CV power supply and battery charger. The regulator will drive the eMOSFEt, which in practice will drive parallel 2N3055 BJTs.

LTspice does not know or care if the IFR510 is severely overloaded or not. The design is similar to a production charger with a fixed current limiter. I want something adjustable to accommodate a wide range of battery capacity. I am looking for an op-amp to build with.